# Can Some one explain thie Apple Review Guideline?

Tags: ios

> Apps can read or play approved content
>   (magazines, newspapers, books, audio,
>   music, video) that is sold outside of
>   the app, for which Apple will not
>   receive any portion of the revenues,
>   provided that the same content is also
>   offered in the app using IAP at the
>   same price or less than it is offered
>   outside the app. This applies to both
>   purchased content and subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Say you're a publisher, and you want to sell subscriptions to your content. Until a week or two ago, the only way to sell content to be displayed in an iOS app was to use in-app purchase, and Apple would take their usual 30% cut. This new rule says that you, the publisher, may now also sell subscriptions outside the app and still let your users use the content in the app, and Apple doesn't expect to get a cut of those subscription fees. So, for example, you can give all the subscribers to your print edition access to the electronic version of your content. Or you can sell subscriptions on your web site without paying Apple a share of the proceeds. However, you can't encourage your app users to avoid IAP by charging a higher price for IAP purchases than you do for outside purchases.